# What is Calvin exactly doing with the oxygen torches by holding?

Tags: plot-explanation, life

In Life (2017), Calvin is holding each oxygen torch for a few seconds with its tentacles and losing it.

[image]

We can see the oxygen torch glowing through the transparent skin of Calvin. What is he doing there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Absorbing nutrients.

The oxygen torch is creating **energy, heat, light, and oxygen**. We do not know for sure which of these things Calvin actually needs, but we can assume he is holding the torch to absorb as much of it as possible.